# Clicking in ssh terminal causes 'junk' characters [0;83;32M0] after tmux

Tags: ssh, mouse, gnome-terminal, tmux

Both my local and remote are Ubuntu 18, though I have seen it in 16 as well.

I establish a ssh to my remote server, start tmux (`2.1.3`), something causes the pipe to break. When I ssh back in, but before I start tmux, whenever I click in the terminal screen, it writes a bunch of junk to the buffer, like

`0;38;15M`
`0;38;15m`
`0;60;12M0;60;12m0;56;14M0;56;14m0;56;14M0;56;14m0;54;13M0;54;13m0;54;13M0;54;13m`

I've deduced that these numbers are of the form `N;X;YM`, where N is 0, 1, 2... for left click, middle, right click, X and Y are proportional to the location of the mouse click, `M` is mouse down, `m` is mouse up.

Clearly, this is some kind of in-band signalling, and I am pretty sure it relates to `option mouse on`. But where is it coming from? Is it just a Tmux thing, an ssh thing, or a Gnome terminal thing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

These are escape sequences that tell tmux about mouse events. Because tmux was disconnected unexpectedly it didn't get a chance to turn mouse mode off so the terminal is still sending them even though no application wants them. You can run "reset" to turn it off.

Comment: Cool! That reset trick was handy. So is this something in the underlying TTY spec to pick up mouse events? I imagine the terminal emulator must be picking up the mouse events and converting them to the escape codes?

Comment: Right the terminal emulator gets mouse events from X or whatever and sends them to the application (if it requests them).

Comment: The stuff you are seeing is SGR mouse mode, there are several others. It's in here somewhere https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: Ah, precisely what I was looking for! Not at all surprised X is behind this. So cool.

Comment: run `reset` or `tput reset`